# Why after calling one command the next one doesn't execute?

Tags: batch-file

After calling script which turns off Windows UAC the next commands don't execute. What am i doing wrong?

```
call C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
call "C:\1c\1CEnterprise 8.msi" /qr TRANSFORMS=adminstallrelogon.mst;1049.mst DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 THICKCLIENT=1 THINCLIENTFILE=1 THINCLIENT=1 WEBSERVEREXT=0 SERVER=0 CONFREPOSSERVER=0 CONVERTER77=0 SERVERCLIENT=0 LANGUAGES=RU,ENG,UKR
call xcopy C:\1c\ibases.v8i C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\1C\1CEStart\. /Y
call rmdir "C:\1c\" /S /Q
call del "C:\1c.zip" 2> nul 
call cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\common\"
call start 1cestart.exe
```

After executing first command cmd.exe just throws me back to the string "C:\Usera\Admin\Desktop" and that is all

Comment: why the `call`s? We only `call` batch files or if delayedexansion is not wanted in certain cases. Remove `call` everywhere. you also do not need to start the commands in new windows. i.e the first line can just be `%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

Comment: and read `cmd /?`. Are you sure, `/k` is what you want (vs. `/c`)?

Comment: "why the calls? We only call batch files or if delayedexansion is not wanted in certain cases. Remove call everywhere. you also do not need to start the commands in new windows. i.e the first line can just be %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"